# Components don't re-render after a change in the Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to make a To do list. I nicked UI from Redux example of that, and I started to write the logic in my own way. I was faced with a problem.
So, the problem is that when I click on  Mark All Completed button all my checkmarks on to dos are not visible on UI, but the state is updated, which is perfectly visible in Redux Dev Tool.
Please, help me to understand what is the matter.

gitHub:https://github.com/Alexander-Korniichuk/Redux_Practice/commit/6c981f47d068614b56ab37410210e43869f7247d

Here I dispatch an action. (Footer.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {markAllCompleted} from "../actions";


const Footer = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <footer className="footer">
            <div className="actions">
                <h5>Actions</h5>
                <button className="button"
                        onClick={() => dispatch(markAllCompleted())}>
                    Mark All Completed
                </button>
                <button className="button">
                    Clear Completed
                </button>
            </div>

            <RemainingTodos/>
            <StatusFilter/>
            <ColorFilters/>
        </footer>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

Right here I select the Completed field of the needed object and paste it into defaultValue (TodoListItem.js)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {ReactComponent as TimesSolid} from './times-solid.svg';
import {markCompleted, deleteToDo, addColor} from "../actions";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";


const TodoListItem = ({todo}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {text, id} = todo;
    const completed = useSelector(state => state.todos.find(item => item.id === id).completed);
    const colorNames = useSelector(state => state.filters.filterColors);
    const [innerSelectColor, setInnerSelectColor] = useState("");

    console.log(completed);
    console.log("render TodoListItem");

    const colorSetter = (e) => {
        dispatch(addColor(id, e.target.value));
        setInnerSelectColor(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <li>
            <div className="view">
                <div className="segment label">
                    <input className="toggle"
                           type="checkbox"
                           defaultChecked={completed}
                           onClick={() => dispatch(markCompleted(id, completed))}
                    />
                    <div className="todo-text">{text}</div>
                </div>

                <div className="segment buttons">
                    <select className="colorPicker"
                            onChange={colorSetter}
                            style={{color: innerSelectColor}}
                    >
                        {colorNames.map((color, index) =>
                            <option key={index} value={color}>{color.toUpperCase()}</option>)}
                    </select>

                    <button className="destroy" onClick={() => dispatch(deleteToDo(id))}>
                        <TimesSolid/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}

export default React.memo(TodoListItem);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show `markAllCompleted` and related reducer

Comment: All actions (src/features/actions.js)

Comment: Reducer (src/features/reducerSilces/todosSlice.js)